# Configuration Error in mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to add authentication and authorization to my website.I'm ding it with a help of tutorial. I added to web.config file and global.asax file following code as the tutorial does.But it gives me an error when i try to run the application.can anyone explain the error that i'v done..I created project by choosing "NO authentication" and I've installed Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers and  Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data packages.....I also added the WebMatrix.Data and WebMatrix.WebData referencesto the application

web.config file

```
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />


<membership defaultProvider="ePlannerProvider">
<providers>
<clear />
<add name="ePlannerProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.ePlannerProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
</providers>  
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true"/>

</system.web>
```

Global.asax file

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("EPlannerDatabaseEntities", "User", "Id", "Email", false);
```

Error message:

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'WebMatrix.WebData.ePlannerProvider' from assembly 'WebMatrix.WebData'.

Source Error:

```
<providers>
<clear />
<add name="ePlannerProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.ePlannerProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
</providers>  
</membership>
```

Answer (score 0):

Error message says the type is not found.

Try to see version is right and use object browser to see if the class exists.

Also in reference, go to properties and set copy local as true.

Typically class names start with capital character